# Effects of gravity on diffusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, physics

I'm just now learning the diffusion model and it seems that we aren't taking into account the acceleration due to gravity of the particles.  Is this a shortcoming of the model or irrelevant? I don't have much experience with physics but this seems like an important factor.

Comment: The effect gravity has is to introduce a macroscopic drift. Diffusion is concerned with concentration gradients so gravity does not typically contribute. I think this question is more suitable for physics stack exchange in either case.

Comment: Gravity would be significant (with molecules of different weights) at very large scales, or in a centrifuge.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most models of physical processes, expressed as PDEs in most textbooks, are very *model* and do not take into account some external forces. These are 'model' equations, for example, the heat equation or a wave equation. In most cases, one can think that the right part $F$ of the equation, for example,
$$ {\partial \phi \over \partial t} - D  \nabla^2 \phi = F $$
contains all the external forces (including gravity, air resistance, etc.)

I most 1D or 2D cases, we just ignore the 'vertical' forces, such as gravity. For a 3D diffusion equations, considering external forces like gravity, consult the fluid dyncamics stacialists, but keep in mind these equation will be much more complex and *very* nonlinear (and hard to investigate!)

P.S. Remember the derivation of a wave equation from most PDE textbooks, You'll notice we always skip lots of forces there.

Comment: Add: You could also take a look at a *convection-diffusion equation*, which is a more generic model for heat&mass transfer.